# Changing value from dropdown using selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, dropdown

The dropdown has four options: `entire duration`, `the most recent 1 week`, `the most recent 1 month`, and `write your own`. I would like to change the value (i.e., date) from the write your own option.

See the screenshot below:

[image: from the website]
[image: from the developer tools]

highlight parts are the values I would like to change.

I used the code:

```
driver.find_element(By. XPATH, '//*[@id="searchPeriod1"]').click()
start_date = driver.find_element(By. XPATH, '//*[@id="s_t_1_162566497815552"]')
end_date = driver.find_element(By. XPATH, '//*[@id="s_t_2_162566497815552"]')
start_date.clear()
start_date.send_keys('2016.01.01')
end_date.clear()
end_date.send_keys('2016.01.31')
driver.find_element(By. XPATH, '//*[@id="s_b_162566497815552"]/ul/li[4]/p[2]').click()
```

I get traceback that there is

```
no such element on the line: 
    driver.find_element(By. XPATH, '//*[@id="s_t_1_162566497815552"]')
```

Comment: Can you share URL of the application if it is public?

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not public.

Comment: Can you check `id=s_t_1_162566497815552`, if this value is dynamic? i.e. check if the value changes each time the page is refreshed?

Comment: I just checked, and you are right! It changes every time I refresh the page! Thank you so much! I should use a different selector.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. If you need help with a different selector, edit your question and add the HTML in the text form instead of image form.